# Calling methods in a C++ application from a C# dll

Tags: c#, c++

*Clarification. There is a C++ exe and a C# exe. The C# exe is a wrapper for a C# dll. I need the dll to call a logger function in the C++ code (so that only one log file is produced). Currently there is a c++/CLI bridge which allows the C++ exe to call methods in the C# dll.*

Apologies if this is a poor question. Its possibly a case of I just don't know what to search for / results for what I am searching for isn't of much use.

I have an application written in C++. It calls a tool written in C#. It appears the executable for the tool is just a wrapper for a c# dll.
The tools purpose is to analyse and display data. The main application calls it for example to have it open a new file. The tool has never had to call anything in the C++ code before so this has always been one way. It appears to be implemented via a C++/CLI bridge. The bridge calls the functions in the tool api.

It is now required for the tool to call some methods in the C++ application. I have no idea how to go about implementing this. My c# / C++/CLI experience is somewhere between poor and non-existent. I started by attempting to clone the C++/CLI bridge and "reverse" it, but since the C# code is in effect a library calling it from the bridge is fairly simple.
However, i'm not really sure (if its even possible) how to call the C++ application from a bridge.

So far the only workable solution I can think of is to have the c# code output to a file (or hopefully shared memory) then the c++ code check it periodically. This isn't close to ideal.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate question. Have you tried this: http://bit.ly/1ah8rhc ?

Comment: I am trying to do the opposite. I need the C# dll to call a method from C++. Everything I have found seems to relate to a c++ library. I may be being dim, but I think slightly less than you presumed.

Comment: Funny thing is I see these questions passing by every month or so, but it's hard to find them. Anyway the answer is always the saem: use P/Invoke (the hard way), or write a CLI layer in between (THE way as far as I'm concerned)

Comment: Also you might want to clarify your question. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to remove the tool executable and include the underlying .Net dll into your c++ application? Or do you want to setup some kind of interaction and data exchange between the two applications? It's not quite clear.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about accessing the C++ functions from the CLI? Googling that seems to provide the opposite...

Comment: @user2036256 edit your question title then :) Because it states the opposite. Tho it doesnt change the fact, that this question was asked 1000 times on stack overflow

Comment: It's probably better to clarify your question yes. And calling C++ from C++/CLI is just, erm, calling it. You don't have to do anything special for that.

Comment: @Nik, Im feeling like im missing something? "Calling methods in a C++ application from a C# dll" is the title. Your link is "calling c# method from C++"?
As for a question update I will do. But I want to keep everything existing as it is, just add some additional calls to the C++ code from the C# dll.

Comment: So @stijn it doesn't matter that its not a library? Ok, thanks :D I think I can figure this out. Since everything i searched for was talking about calling libraries I think I was too fast in presuming it wasn't the same.

Comment: @user2036256 ah, ok. I guess, i'm just confusing "in C++ from C#" with "in c# from c++". %) Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think i'll throw in a suggestion here.

Depending on what your goal is:

1) Goal: execute some of your c++ logic from c# code.

Solution: this one is fairly simple. You extract logic of interest into separate C++ project, build it as a library and then use it in both applications. As you said, there are plenty examples on how to call c++ dll from c# code.

2) Goal: froce your c++ application to execute some of it's logic from C# application.

Solution: it all comes to setting up an interprocess communication. There are quite a few approaches, that are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). I suggest using [NamedPipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb546085.aspx) but you are free to pick w/e you are comfortable with.

Edit: Judging by your edit you probably want the second solution.

Comment: I think you are right, the simplest solution now seems to be just have a dll with all the logger code and call it from both.
Seems so simple now! One of those slamming your head against a wall moments...

Comment: @user2036256 be careful with the first approach tho. If you use single dll for both applications, you will still have _two_ logger's instances (one per application). This will cause exceptions, if those loggers will try to lock the same text file at the same time (for writing, for example).

Comment: That *shouldn't* be able to happen. The code only logs user actions, so unless the user can move between windows and fire a command faster than the read/write can occur then it should be ok.
But i'll add some basic exception handling to be safe. Thanks